# I Cannot send mail via smtp telnet in linux

Tags: smtp, telnet

I tried sending mail in telnet  in linux as

```
telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
```

but it returns the error

```
telnet: connect to address to remote host: Connection timed out
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

Any one please help

Comment: Handwritten SMTP via telnet is easy (even I was able to do it back in the day), but TLS is not.

Comment: I tried Port 25 also. But no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would blame your local network - possibly a firewall somewhere. I am able to telnet to smtp.gmail.com on port 587 without any issue from here.